# Optimize battery lifespan on a LENOVO ideapad 510

Tags: laptop, power-management, lenovo, battery

I bought a new LENOVO ideapad 510. Most of the time I will use my new laptop connected to the AC power and only rarely will need a full battery. I have dual OS Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.10.

My question is: how can I optimize the battery lifespan?

I have installed tlp but I cannot control the battery start/stop loading thresholds for this model. Any suggestion other than manually plug at 40% of the battery unplug at 50% of the battery?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no Linux tool for charge thresholds on non-ThinkPads.

Your only option is to install Windows dual boot and configure the thresholds with Energy Manager or Lenovo Companion. thresholds are stored in hardware and persist when you boot Linux again.

Comment: Mmm, I see. I already have dual boot windows 10/Ubuntu 16.10. However, it seems that there is not such an app for windows 10 either (see https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-10/Power-Manager-for-Windows-10/m-p/2129075#M794)... Any suggestion?